# Remove a specific character of plaintext with simple dom html

Tags: html-parsing

I have this code to retrieve some products on a website:

```
foreach($page1->find('.link_category') as $produit1) 
echo $produit1->plaintext . '<br />';
```

I retrieve product with double quote ", i would like to replace it (the double quote)by nothing

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($page1->find('.link_category') as $produit1) {
$product = str_replace('"','',$produit1->plaintext);
echo $product;
}
```

I hope it works :)